# How is it possible that not even the driver noticed the flat tire during the journey?

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation

A family of 4 people drove in their car for about 250 miles at an average speed of 60 miles/hour.
When they reached their destination, the kids noticed that they had a flat tire.

How is it possible that not even the driver noticed the flat tire during the journey?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it was the

> spare tire that is flat.

Answer (score 3):

The flat tire was

> On their other car (at home, their destination).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps,

> After reaching the destination, a tyre became flat.

Answer (score 0):

The car was

> being transported,on a train or a ferry. During the journey,the car's wheels were not moving,so no-one noticed the flat tyre until the end,when it was time for it to start up again.